# Trigger itemupdated eventhandler when an item is Added in an SPList

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, event-handlers, itemupdated, item-added

I have written an itemupdated event receiver for a SPList in my SP 2013 / VS 2013 solution [ on-premises] . Now I want to trigger this itemupdated event when the item is created in the SPList .But when i added an item in the splist its not triggering this  itemupdated event

i have noticed that , itemupdated event and itemcheckedin event triggered for a documentlibrary[ version enabled].
but for a splist whose versioning is **NOT**  enabled , this itemupdated event handler is not working.

How can i trigger an itemupdated eventhandler for a splistitem when an item is added into the splist ?

```
public class NPDListEvntRcvr : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An item was added.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
       // base.ItemAdded(properties);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An item was updated.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        //base.ItemUpdated(properties);


        SPUser currUser = properties.Web.CurrentUser;

        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

        try
        {

            // if (properties.ListTitle.ToLower() == NPDListNames.ITEMLEVELPERMISSIONSLIST.ToString())
            // {

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {

                SPSite CurrentSite = new SPSite(properties.SiteId);
                SPWeb CurrentWeb = CurrentSite.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl);

                SPList CurrentList = CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId];

                SPListItem CurrentListItem;
                CurrentListItem = CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId].GetItemById(properties.ListItem.ID);
                // = IsDocumentLibrary(CurrentListItem);
             //   blnIsSPList = IsSPList(CurrentListItem);
             //   blnIsFolderinDocLib = IsFolderDocumenttLibrary(CurrentListItem);

               // string authorFieldValue = CurrentListItem["Author"].ToString();
                SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(CurrentWeb, CurrentListItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author].ToString());
                SPUser author = userValue.User;


                if (!CurrentListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                {
                    CurrentListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                    CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
```

Comment: Use the `itemadded ` event

Comment: what will happen if i update an item in the list by using the Edit-->Edit properties. am not able to trigger the / apply the itempermissions in the itemadded eventhandler , since i added the  code in the itemupdated eventhandler method. but this holds true for a document library item.it fires both itemadded and itemupdated in the case of doc .lib

Comment: it will trigger the `itemupdated` event.

Comment: in SPList , can i trigger the itemupdatedevethandler using the itemadded event? is this by design ? as suggested by you, i need to duplicate the code , thats wrtten in the itemupdated eventhandler. wont it be a bad practice?

Comment: No, when you click on `add new item` and save it, it will trigger `itemadded` event. So do you want the same process to trigger for `itemadded` and `itemupdated` ?

Comment: ok, for me, when an new item is created in the splist, i wanna fire  applypermissions method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52573/discussion-between-samolpp-and-gautam-sheth).